# Split string and get start index of returned results

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to split a string on some delimeters and get the index of the returned strings in the original string.  Like a `MatchCollection` returned by `Regex.Matches`.

something like

```
MatchCollection col = Regex.Split(text, @"[\.\-]");
```

what pattern can I pass to `Regex.Matches` that would return a `MatchCollection` split along my delimeters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex as usual, and capture the text in groups. Here, we name each group as `part`, and use the `\.\-` as delimiters for these parts:

```
string text = "hi.there-how-are.you";
MatchCollection col = Regex.Matches(text,
    @"((?<part>[^\.\-]+)(\.\-))*(?<part>[^\.\-]+)");
foreach (Match match in col) {
    var part = match.Groups["part"];
    Console.WriteLine(part.Value + " at " + part.Index);
}
```

So basically `(<part><delimiter>)*<part>`. Output:

```
hi at 0
there at 3
how at 9
are at 13
you at 17
```